# plot two seaborn heatmap graphs side by side

Tags: python, numpy, plot, heatmap, seaborn

I'm attempting to plot two seaborn graphs side by side as other graphs (successfully) have done in previous questions, only difference I can see is that heatmaps seems to be throwing an issue. The code to produce the error is:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)    
uniform_data2 = np.random.rand(100, 120)

fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)

ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data2)
```

Which produces the below

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just have to use the `ax` parameter

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax1)
sns.heatmap(uniform_data2, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9):

You have created an array of axes using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)`. You are then overwriting that array with the result of `sns.heatmap`. Instead, you want to specify which axes you want to plot to using the `ax=` argument of `sns.heatmap`:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)    
uniform_data2 = np.random.rand(100, 120)

fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax[0])
sns.heatmap(uniform_data2, ax=ax[1])

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]